# How to show custom image for different values from attribute magento

Tags: magento, attributes

i want to get images according the values from an attribute on magento.

Example:

```
Attribute > MyAttribute
Values > Nasa, Google, Linux

Images > Nasa.jpg, Google.jpg, Linux.jpg

Products >

Product Nasa < Get Nasa.jpg if is selected an attribute
Product Google < Get Google.jpg if is selected an attribute
Product Linux < Get Linux.jpg if is selected an attribute
```

This script is to show if is selected yes.

```
<?php if($_product->getMyAttribute()): ?>
<img src="/path/to/the/image.jpg">
<?php endif; ?>
```

I found a solution by myself. Below the script.

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('myattribute') == "Text Inside"): ?> 
<div id="some"><img src="image.jpg"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: if you got the answer write in answer part ... it confuses others also

Answer (score 1):

Johann Reinke's [Attribute Option Images](https://github.com/jreinke/magento-attribute-option-image) extension should do exactly what you want.  It even provides an admin UI for an administrator to be able to maintain the images. Johann's extension is free, open source and on Guthub.

Comment: Thanks Jim, is a nice extension.

Comment: If my (or anyone else's) answers have helped you out, don't forget to accept an answer.  Also don't forget to vote for any questions or answers that you find helpful.  SO user's love Reputation points (or "rep")!